# Visual Studio Android Emulator Display Keyboard

Tags: android, emulation, visual-studio-2015

How can I display keyboard on VS Android Emulator?
In AVD I can setup it from emulator configurator, but there is no way in VS.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I found a solution in Android Setting → Language Input → Keyboard
Click on Current Keyboard and switch "Hardware Show Input Method"

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N52ff.png]

Comment: I can't find this setting on the VS Emulator 10.1" KitKat (4.4) HDPI Tablet. Maybe it's only on later OS versions?

Comment: @BobMeyers In KitKat (4.4) try going to Settings > Language & Input > Keyboard & Input methods (section) > Default, and turn "Hardware (Physical keyboard)" switch off.

Comment: I also found that once the hardware setting was changed (thanks to @Dan Dar3 for the new method) I have to restart the emulator as certain normal text keys were launching apps on the emulated phone.