# Where are emoji characters in Visual Studio Android Emulator

Tags: visual-studio, android-emulator

I am using the Visual Studio Android Emulator.  The emoji characters defined for Android do not seem to exist.

The answer to this question [Visual Studio Android Emulator Display Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31409410/visual-studio-android-emulator-display-keyboard) showed me how to display the emulator's keyboard.

However the keyboard does not have the emoji characters which are present on Android hardware devices.  So this is more than a keyboard issue...the characters do not seem to exist in the font that the emulator uses to display text.

I discovered this by trying to do a react-native tutorial, https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/handling-text-input.html, which uses the pizza slice emoji.  It took me a while to realize that the reason it wasn't working was a problem with the emulator rather than the tutorial.  When I switched to a hardware Android device, the tutorial worked fine.

So how to enable the emoji characters on the VS Android emulator?  Is this a bug, an oversight, a licensing issue?  Hopefully it is a simple configuration problem.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No and I haven't really been looking for a solution.  Emojis for your Android emulator are probably not critical.  It is troubling because it makes me wonder in what other areas the VS emulator falls short.